# Is Windows 10 halal?

Tags: piracy

Windows 10 from it's official website is free for download. Is using it to earn money online halal or it is haram in islam? How can I use it in halal ways without purchasing it?

Answer (score 2):

You say this is from its official website. So it's not piracy, as Microsoft have given it to you freely. If you're concerned, read the [terms and conditions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm) to see if your usage is legal.

I'm not aware of anything saying you can't use something given to you freely, in the way it was intended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use it for your personal use but you can not sell something for which you dont have any rights to sell. So i think according to islam you cant sell it to earn money without a valid contract or Rights.

Answer (score -2):

Its so so halal frpm offical website if you created cracking app and cracked him haram
if you downloaded crack from people and you did not make it halal

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. This answer could benefit from provided external sources to support your answer.